# ArgumentException when inserting a Form in WindowsFormsHost

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, forms, com

In WPF app I have created `WindowsFormsHost` and wanted to insert in it a `Form` containing `COM`/`Activex` control. But then I get:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in WindowsFormsIntegration.dll
   at System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost.set_Child(Control value)
   at HomeSecurity.MainWindow..ctor() w c:\Users\R\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\HomeSecurity\HomeSecurity\MainWindow.xaml.cs:row 26
'HomeSecurity.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: HomeSecurity.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\UIAutomationTypes\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\UIAutomationTypes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
```

This is the contstructor of `MainWindow`. Class `VideoStream` extends class `Form`

```
      public MainWindow() {
           InitializeComponent();
           VideoStream VideoStream = new VideoStream();//creating a Form containing Activex control
           WindowsFormsHost Host = new WindowsFormsHost();//creating a host
           try {
               Host.Child = VideoStream;//setting content of Host, CAUSES THE EXCEPTION PRINTED ABOVE
           }catch(Exception e){
               Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);//output above
           }
        }
```

I cannot deal with it for long time and I have no more time. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, You can't add a `Form`(TopLevelControl) inside it. You'll have to make it child control first. Setting `TopLevel` is set to false should make it work.

```
VideoStream.TopLevel = false;
```

Note: Not only with `WindowsFormsHost`, even with Winforms application also you can't add a `Form` inside a `Form` unless `TopLevel` is set to false.

Comment: Man! You are my hero! Nobody wanted to help me before in that. I couldn't deal with that for few days. This is my question put in a hard way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912025/argumentexception-occurs-when-inserting-form-containing-activex-control-into-win

Comment: I'll put a bounty in a 2 days and award it... exception gone! Thank you again.

Comment: IMP, Happy to see that your problem solved. Cheers:)

Answer (score 2):

Why not derive `VideoStream` from [`UserControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) rather than from `Form`? IMO, that'd be more appropriate for re-using and hosting it inside a WPF app, and the problem would have been gone.

**[EDITED]** You should first add the `WindowsFormsHost` control to the WPF window, then add your `UserControl`-derived `VideoStream` control to the `WindowsFormsHost` control:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Forms.Integration;

namespace WpfWinformsTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // add a grid first (optional)
            var grid = new Grid();
            this.Content = grid;

            // create and add a WinForms host
            WindowsFormsHost host = new WindowsFormsHost(); 
            grid.Children.Add(host);

            // add a WinForms user control
            var videoStream = new VideoStream();
            host.Child = videoStream;
        }
    }
}
```

You can do the same with XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfWinformsTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfWinformsTest" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost Name="wfHost" Focusable="True" Margin="10,10,10,10">
            <local:VideoStream x:Name="videoStream" />
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here's how `VideoStream` may look like (of course, you can use VS Designer to add controls like `axVideoPlayer` to it, rather than doing it manually):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WpfWinformsTest
{
    public partial class VideoStream : UserControl
    {
        AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer axVideoPlayer;

        public VideoStream()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.axVideoPlayer = new AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer();
            this.axVideoPlayer.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
            this.Controls.Add(this.axVideoPlayer);
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest you read the following articles:

[Walkthrough: Hosting a Windows Forms Composite Control in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750944%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Walkthrough: Hosting an ActiveX Control in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Could you show it how it should be done. I was programming in Java for a years, and I lack of ".NET intuition", I am noob right now.

Comment: @Yoda, you probably have a definition like this somewhere in your C# source file: `public partial class VideoStream: Form`. Just change it to `public partial class VideoStream: UserControl`, that should do it.

Comment: When I derive `VideoStream` from `UserControl` I get: A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
   w System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection.Add(Visual visual)
   w System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.AddInternal(UIElement element)
   w System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.Add(UIElement element)
   w HomeSecurity.MainWindow..ctor() w c:\Users\R\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\HomeSecurity\HomeSecurity\MainWindow.xaml.cs:wiersz 28

Comment: @Yoda, you should actually add the `WindowsFormsHost` control to the WPF window first. Refer to my updated answer.